# Asyncpg INSERT query for timestamp returns ERROR syntax error at or near "18"

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py, asyncpg

Hi I'm getting an error that occurs when trying to add the timestamp. I keep getting the error `asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "18"` and this line `end_date = duration + dt.datetime.now(bst) # timestamp` seems to be the culprit however I'm unsure why this is the case.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
    if time is not None:
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL)
        async with conn.transaction():
            await conn.fetch(f"SELECT time FROM blacklist WHERE username={member.id}")
        
            duration = find_date(time)
            bst = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
            end_date = duration + dt.datetime.now(bst) # timestamp
            fmt_date = end_date.strftime("%#d %b %Y, at %I:%M%p")
            await conn.fetch(f"UPDATE blacklist SET time={end_date} WHERE username={member.id}")
        
            await member.add_roles(restricted, reason=f'Restricted role added by {author.name}')
            await member.remove_roles(members)
            
            await conn.close()

            msg = f"{member} has been restricted until {fmt_date}."
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Restricted", description=msg, colour=author.color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass the arguments in `f-strings` when dealing with SQL queries, the syntax for query arguments in `asyncpg` is `$n`, also I see that you're using the `Connection.fetch` method but you're simply updating the table, I'd suggest you to use `Connection.execute`

Your code fixed:

```py
end_date = # Should be a datetime.datetime instance
await conn.execute("""
    UPDATE blacklist 
    SET time = $1 
    WHERE username = $2
""", end_date, member.id)
```

Removing timezone awareness

```py
end_date = # `datetime.datetime` instance
naive = end_date.replace(tzinfo=None)
await conn.execute("""
    UPDATE blacklist 
    SET time = $1 
    WHERE username = $2
""", naive, member.id)
```

#### References:

- [`Connection.execute`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.execute)

*PS: Don't create a new connection everytime you want to use it, normal practice is to have one long-term database connection*

Comment: I'm getting `InterfaceError: cannot call Transaction.__aexit__(): the underlying connection is closed` not sure if it's a related error.

Comment: The issue might be that you're closing the connection inside the context manager, put the conn.close call outside of it

Comment: `await conn.execute("""UPDATE blacklist  SET time = $1 WHERE username = $2""", naive, member.id)` doesn't seem to be working. Nothing is being added to the username or time columns.

Comment: You're updating the time, are you sure there's nothing being added? Any errors/tracebacks?

Comment: It turns out the discord.py `on_member_update` event that was causing the issue.